# How do I compare and combine two object array into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been stuck trying to implement this forever. do you think you could help me out merging two array objects based on the key `PartitionKey` and if the `PartitionKey` don't match up, still add it to the array anyway?

```
let arr1 =[
  { PartitionKey: '047', AttributionCount: 61 },
  { PartitionKey: '043', AttributionCount: 136 },
  { PartitionKey: '053', AttributionCount: 36 }
];

let arr2 = [
  { PartitionKey: '043', ReportCount: 5 },
  { PartitionKey: '047', ReportCount: 2 },
  { PartitionKey: '045', ReportCount: 2 },
  { PartitionKey: '041', ReportCount: 3 }
]

let arr3 = arr1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]));

console.log(arr3);
```

I would like to return the result of

```
[
  { PartitionKey: '047', ReportCount: 2, AttributionCount: 61 },
  { PartitionKey: '043', ReportCount: 5, AttributionCount: 136 },
  { PartitionKey: '053', ReportCount: 0, AttributionCount: 36 },
  { PartitionKey: '045', ReportCount: 2, AttributionCount: 0},
  { PartitionKey: '041', ReportCount: 3, AttributionCount: 0}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my way...

```js
let arr1 = 
  [ { PartitionKey: '047', AttributionCount:  61 } 
  , { PartitionKey: '043', AttributionCount: 136 } 
  , { PartitionKey: '053', AttributionCount:  36 } 
  ] 
let arr2 = 
  [ { PartitionKey: '043', ReportCount: 5 } 
  , { PartitionKey: '047', ReportCount: 2 } 
  , { PartitionKey: '045', ReportCount: 2 } 
  , { PartitionKey: '041', ReportCount: 3 } 
  ] 

const result = 
  Object.entries( 
    arr1
    .concat(arr2)
    .reduce((res,{PartitionKey,...info}) =>
      {
      if (!res[PartitionKey]) res[PartitionKey] = info
      else      Object.assign(res[PartitionKey], info )
      return res
      }
      ,{})
  ).map( ([k,v]) =>
    ({PartitionKey:k, AttributionCount:0, ReportCount:0, ...v}))

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
let arr1 =[
  { PartitionKey: '047', AttributionCount: 61 },
  { PartitionKey: '043', AttributionCount: 136 },
  { PartitionKey: '053', AttributionCount: 36 }
];

let arr2 = [
  { PartitionKey: '043', ReportCount: 5 },
  { PartitionKey: '047', ReportCount: 2 },
  { PartitionKey: '045', ReportCount: 2 },
  { PartitionKey: '041', ReportCount: 3 }
]

let arr3 = arr2.map((item, i) => {
  const itemArray1 = arr1.find(x => x.PartitionKey == item.PartitionKey) || {AttributionCount: 0}
  return {...item, ...itemArray1}
});

console.log('arr3', arr3);
```

Comment: where is `{ PartitionKey: '053', ReportCount: 0, AttributionCount: 36 }` ?

Comment: Sorry I thougth he wants to map arrys. I need to edit my answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `object.assign()` method for this problem.

e.g: `const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);`

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the benchmark is good.

```js
let arr1 = [
  { PartitionKey: '047', AttributionCount: 61 },
  { PartitionKey: '043', AttributionCount: 136 },
  { PartitionKey: '053', AttributionCount: 36 },
];

let arr2 = [
  { PartitionKey: '043', ReportCount: 5 },
  { PartitionKey: '047', ReportCount: 2 },
  { PartitionKey: '045', ReportCount: 2 },
  { PartitionKey: '041', ReportCount: 3 },
];

let map = new Map();

[...arr1, ...arr2].forEach((item) => {
  let itemPk = item.PartitionKey;
  map.set(itemPk, { PartitionKey: 0, ReportCount: 0, AttributionCount: 0, ...map.get(itemPk), ...item });
});

let result = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.